# how do i close a branch on mercurial without using "hg ci --close-branch"?

Tags: mercurial

for some reason "hg ci --close-branch" is coming up as an command not found in my mercurial. how do I get around this to close the branch in a different way?

thanks!

Comment: Does `hg ci` on its own give problems?  Are you sure you're using two '-' characters in the `--close-branch` option?

Comment: yes :( hg ci --close-branch
hg commit: option --close-branch not recognized

Comment: I don't like updating to an old branch just to close it because it's slow. All the sub-repos get updated and this can take a minute depending on the age of the branch. It seems like a lot of time wasted just to mark a branch as closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mercurial is too old.  Close branch was added in version 1.6 or 1.7.  You should upgrade, which is quite easy on most any platform.

Failing that there's no way to close a branch, but you can make it inactive by merging it into another branch.  Both closed and inactive non-final for a named branch -- they never really go away.